# Companion apps, sites and applications for Ingress

Tags: ingress

I've noticed quite a few companion apps in the Google Play store, but I am naturally terrified that I'll miss out on some essential tool and loose an edge ;)

How would you go about finding good companion apps (phone), applications (pc/mac) or sites/webapps for Ingress?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how good the android version is since my phone is using an older version of Android OS, but for desktop computers the [Ingress Intel Total Conversion](http://iitc.jonatkins.com/) enhancement to the intel map is quite helpful.

Please be warned that IITC is against the Ingress Terms of Service.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend first joining a local G+ Ingress community (there seems to be quite a few), getting in touch with your local Ingressors, and seeing what they use. If there isn't a good community in your area, I'd recommend just trying them all out, and seeing what works best for you. I'd love to hear your critique of any great companion apps or sites that improve the Ingress experience.

In addition, Google Field Trip lets you know when you are passing an Ingress portal outside of the Ingress app, if you have Ingress installed on the same device, and have your account linked to it.

Comment: How do I go about finding my local community on Google+?

Comment: Try searching "ingress X"; x - your city/country/state